# How to get back DateTime from JSON.decode

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, serialization

Are there any alternatives to JSON.decode (or any options to it I'm not aware of) that will parse the JSON with the date/time strings converted to DateTime objects?

```
ActiveSupport::JSON.decode({date_time: DateTime.now()}.to_json)
```

Having to

```
h["dt1"] = DateTime.strptime(h["dt1"])
h["dt2"] = DateTime.strptime(h["dt2"])
```

For each of the DateTime fields is quite annoying.

Or are there any other ways to serialize ruby objects as a string to store in redis and then get back the original object and their members as original objects?

Would Masrhal.dump and Marshal.load be preferred?  Not sure why the redis-rb docs suggest JSON.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the JSON specification does not include a Date/Time data type.

You could use Marshal but that would limit you to only use ruby to write/read from redis. Perhaps a better option would be YAML, which does have a Date/Time type.